# Accessing the image of an entity within groups in drupal 8 in twig override

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I'm using drupal 8, and within my group module, I added a custom field that is related to the user entities where the number is unlimited:

[image]

Within that twig override, I'm attempting to access the user information, specifically the user's profile picture, which is this field:

[image]

Now finally when it comes to the twig override, I can't seem to access the user's image even though it's clearly there (its the last one in the list):

[image]

But the link isn't there. How do I access it? It's not showing a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it through user entity like this:

```
{{ dump(file_url(content.field_project_contributor.0['#options'].entity.user_picture.entity.fileuri)) }}
```

Here I use `file_url()` to convert file URI to relative path on the server.